# how to resolve time data comparism in php

Tags: php

I have a contract time format like this one **July 28, 2020 14:18:25** that I want check if it has expired from now. But am not getting is correct. it seems to be some minutes difference

here is the code

```
//$now = strtotime(date("m-d-y H:i:s"));
$now = time();
$contractDate = strtotime("July 28, 2020 14:18:25");

// check if contract is still on or has ended from now

if($now < $contractDate) {
   echo "contract is on";
} else {
    echo "contract time ended!";  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to get it right because of your format. It should work if you can get your dates to be in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format. Try this:

```
$now = strtotime(date("y-m-d"));
$now = time();
$contractDate = strtotime("2020-07-28");
if($now < $contractDate) {
echo "contract is on";
    } else {
echo "contract time ended!";  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the timezone problem (that your `time()` is off by some).

You solve it by setting the timezone explicitly in your PHP scripts. You can do this with `date_default_timezone_set():`

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Here is the list of [PHP supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

You may also want to try a test script calling `date_default_timezone_get()` to see what it's actually set to to verify that this is in fact the problem.

You can also try with `DateTime` class

```
$d1 = new DateTime();
$d2 = new DateTime("July 28, 2020 14:18:25");
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
echo $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```